# How to change native element from Phonegap plugin?

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to change native TextView value that i pass from cordova plugin. This application will show 2 elements - native element(TextView) and cordova webview in one activity layout. Is it possible to interchange context between main and phonegap to update current UI...
have any one any idea?...

Example concept -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CordovaInterface{
 .....
 .....
 public void changeText(String txt){
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(txt);

 }

}
```

Cordova plugin:

public class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

```
 public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext){
          if (action.equals("changeText")) {
                      ..............
                 }
  }
}
```

Layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
       android:id="@+id/tutorialView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="196dp" />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it works.... 2 elements are important :

- **cordova context**- call textview in plugin class using:

`TextView textView =
   cordova.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);`

- **thread** - invoke the changes in cordova plugin execute using runOnUiThread

eg:-

```
cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
 public void run() {

                textView.setText("Cordova Hello World"); 

                callbackContext.success(); 

                // Thread-safe. 

        } });
```

Comment: Can you share your code, I want to know how did you achieve both native and HTML components in your app.